# Replacing smart quotes with regular quotes

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a Word 2010 document that uses smart quotes (`”`).  I want to find/replace them all with regular quotes (`"`).  When I actually try this, Word says that it found and replaced X occurrences, but the smart quotes are still there, most likely because Word converted them back immediately after the change.

*I do not want to modify my Word settings*.  I only want to replace the smart quotes for this particular document.  I still want regular quotes auto-converted to smart quotes with my other documents so that my settings are consistent with most others' settings.  However, if there were a way to turn off the auto-conversion for this particular document, that would be ideal as well.

Comment: In my job, I frequently have to embed XML and CSV snippets (often syntax-highlighted) in Word documents.  It would be nice to have an easy way to (a) straighten the quotes when they have become 'smartened' against my will for whatever reason (b) disable automatic smart quotes in specific styles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest approach would be if you were to just change your setting for the document, run the find and replace, then change your setting back.  However, as you don't want to do that, the following approach will work for you (ie will replace curly quotes with straight quotes even if proofing settings are set to automatically replace quotes with curly quotes).

The trick is to use wildcard find with numeric character codes so you find both the opening and closing curly quotes, and replace with clipboard contents ^c.

In your Word document, to get a straight double quote, type the quote mark then press CTRL z - this will change it from your automatically reformatted curly quote back to a straight double quote.

Select the straight quote and press CTRL c to copy it to clipboard. You can then delete this extra quote mark that you created as you just needed it for the clipboard.

Now you can run your find and replace.  you must select the option to Use Wildcards.. And in the Find what box, type `[` then by holding ALT, enter the characters ALT0147 (numeric keypad) and ALT0148 (numeric keypad) and then `]` - so it looks like `[“”]`  That will search for either of those curly quote characters

In the Replace with box, just type ^c (must be lowercase c)

Your find and replace should now replace all the curly double quotes with straight double quotes.

Comment: +1 that is very good.. also if anybody is interested.. to see the hex of a character you can put the cursor after it and hit ALT-X. And also if somebody is not so big on word as to know that smart quote followed by ctrl-z will produce a straight quote, and that the ctrl-z shortcut after quote won't work in find and replace, and about the ^c which is an awesome shortcut, they can use character map and paste in a straight quote e.g. into the replace box of find and replace..

Comment: This worked!  The ALT+NumPad is a good shortcut.  The key to geeting this to work is to actually use `^c` in the *Replace with* field after copying your regular quote to clipboard.  If you just use `"`, it will not actually replace it.  Not sure why the `^c` is so significant, but I won't bother trying to find out since I've finally found a working solution.

Comment: Thanks! I've never had to selectively replace typographic quotes before and this has saved me a couple of hours.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin I think what actually happens is that when you enter a quote in the 'replace with' box Word performs a 'type' operation, which 'smartens' quotes, but when you enter `^c` it performs a 'paste' operation which doesn't.  But it is a bonkers design.

Comment: Copying a straight quote to the clipboard and using `^c`!  Thanks - that works!  I'll have to use this from now on.